# Badge multiplier in the profile page is misaligned

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, profile-page

The snapshot should be self-explanatory. The per-badge count (`× 3`) is misaligned. Is this a bug?

Seen on Chrome 43+, on Windows 7.

[image: Misaligned badges screen-shot]

---

Additional: [The profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589026/raghu-srikanth-reddy) page from which the snapshot is taken.

---

Update on 06-Aug-2015:

As per the comments, it's repro on

- Firefox 39.0
- Chrome 44 (Win 10 / Mac)

A Cross-meta [dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261902/badge-multiplier-a-little-bit-misaligned-on-the-profile-page)

---

Update on 07-Aug-2015:

Repro on

- IE 11.0.21
- Microsoft Edge on Windows 10

Comment: Also an issue in Firefox 39.0. Only affects the badges on the Profile page, the badges section on the Activity page seems to be aligned correctly.

Comment: It's the same in Chrome 44 on Windows 10, the numbers are misaligned as seen in the OP's screenshot.

Comment: Something recent? I was looking at @Yuret's badges on their profile yesterday and didn't notice it.

Comment: @BillWoodger Not very sure, but yes, at present 5 more can repro this. Waiting for the down-voter to get the knowledge of the non-repro case.

Comment: Forgot to add that I can see the problem now on that user, hence the comment.

Comment: [No repro here :)](http://i.imgur.com/21Y4u2G.png)

Comment: Seeing this in Chrome as well.

Comment: @CayceK I am running Chrome, anyway. :-)

Comment: Yep just confirming that :D wouldn't be helpful if I said seeing this as well. (could be in firefox, safari, edge, ie, etc.. I don't feel like looking everywhere else :P)

Comment: But at the least this is a problem in Firefox 39 as well.

Comment: [MSE dup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261902/badge-multiplier-a-little-bit-misaligned-on-the-profile-page)

Comment: @KyleMit You don't have any multipliers in your screenshot.

Comment: @NathanOliver, at the risk of explaining the joke, but at the benefit of clarity, I was being coy (thus the smiley face).

Comment: @KyleMit Ok.  Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: This issue also occurs on Chrome for Mac OS.

Comment: This also occurs on Microsoft Edge on Windows 10.

Comment: For any Stack Overflow engineers reading this, applying `vertical-align: middle` to the `.badge` element fixes it.

Comment: can confirm this in Firefox 39 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Also confirmed on IE 11.0.21 running on Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Should be fixed in next 24h.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the necessary CSS fix:

```css
.badges-content .rarest .badges-list .badge, .badges-content .rarest .badges-list .badge-tag {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.badges-content .badge-date { 
    padding: 0.4em 0px; /* we don't want to have that mis-aligned either
                           padding matches the one of the .badge (inline-)block */
}
```

The *badges* tab on the *activity* page does look as expected because the badges are displayed in a table there, where a middle alignment is the default. Btw, for consistency you might want to wrap the "× 3" in a `<span class="item-multiplier">`, `<span class="item-multiplier-x">`, `<span class="item-multiplier-count">` like everywhere else.